# Desperate: How to install Haskell School of Expression graphics pkg, Windows XP and 7

Tags: haskell, graphics, installation, expression

I've already downloaded the Haskell platform and I've been using ghci with no problem, but that's about it. I need to use the SOE graphics files, and I downloaded the files (I think it was tar.gz) but wherever I look, the instructions for Windows seem to skip steps or not work. I can't get cabal to work (never in scope) even after I moved it from a buried folder to the bin where ghci lives. Same for OpenGL or GLFW or whatever it's called.

I need clear step by step instructions for my desktop (Win XP SP2) and my laptop (Win 7). If you point me to an existing page, I've probably been there and tried to follow the instructions without success. See if you can clarify the process.

Please talk to me as if I am a moron. If you're telling me to type something, I need to know where I'm typing it. If I need to download a file, tell me what folder it belongs in. Please.

First: Should I uninstall everything I've already downloaded to start fresh, and if so, do I just delete the files or must I get into the registry?

---

I've actually made some progress. I got cabal to install GLFW. I typed -i./SOE/src and I got the right result. Then I went to :load Draw.lhs and got

Compiling SOE ( SOE.hs, interpreted )

SOE.hs:136:31:
Couldn't match expected type 'Bool' with actual type '()'
Expected type: GLFW.WindowCloseCallback
Actual type: IO ()
In the return type of a call of 'closeWindow_'
In the second argument of '($=)', namely 'closeWindow_ eventsChan'
Failed, modules loaded: none

????? I just want to clarify, I didn't do anything to the SOE.hs file myself.

Comment: Not serious: 1. download the latest ubuntu or openSuSe release 2. burn install dvd 3. wipe and install ... serious: if the cabal coming with the Haskell platform doesn't work, that's a bad sign. I would first try to get that fixed and care about graphics libraries thereafter. Unfortunately I can't help you fixing it, since my knowledge of Windows is minuscule.

Comment: Also not a Windows expert, but if `cabal` isn't in scope, that usually means you need to fix your `PATH`. Moving executables from where they expect to be is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: The cabal.exe file was buried in a folder under lib, something like "other" and when it didn't work there, and I read somewhere it has to be in the path, I took to mean that if cabal.exe were in the same folder as ghci.exe it couldn't possibly not be in the path, so I moved it there. How do I fix my path?

Comment: This page http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal-Install#Windows says to put it in C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin

Comment: Right! So why wouldn't it be in the path? I saw elsewhere to put something like -i.\SoeGraphics to put it in the path but I got another error message.

Comment: This works for me: on a fresh Win7, use the instructions at Hudak's SOE page, but add "cabal update".  Here's what I did: 1) download and install Haskell Platform (used 2011.4.0.0, which gives ghc 7.0.3)   2) open cmd window  3) cabal update  4) cabal install GLFW  5) download and unzip SOE files  6) in the cmd window, cd to the SOE/src directory, and run  ghci SimpleGrahpics.lhs
7) at the ghci prompt, run main0, or main1, or main3book
However, I have to kill the OpenGL window, spaceClose doesn't work., robably a buffering issue with ghci, but didn't work compiled either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say that cabal doesn't work for you because it is "not in scope", it sounds like you are trying to run cabal from inside GHCi (because the error message there would be `Not in scope: 'cabal'`).

Cabal is a completely separate program, which you need to run from the Windows command prompt. If it doesn't work from there, I'd suggest uninstalling and then reinstalling the Haskell platform (especially if you have moved files around manually). The Haskell Platform installer should always add the `cabal` command to your path (although you need to reopen any command prompt windows to use the updated path).

You absolutely do not need to move any executable files to different folders or anything like that (I've used the Haskell Platform under Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7).

Comment: You are right, Shang, I was trying to use it inside GHCI. I'm not at my computer now but hopefully your advice works.

Comment: I tried following the instructions at http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/hudak/SOE/software1.htm.

Comment: The screen was too large to paste here so I edited my original question.

Comment: How do I uninstall the Haskell platform? Just delete the folder? There's no uninstall program that I can see.

Comment: I'm not at a Windows machine at the moment, so I can't check the details, but I think there should be an uninstall options if you go to Control Panel (via the Windows Start menu) and then choose Add/Remove Programs. Look for Haskell Platform in the program list there. If Haskell Platform is not listed there, you can try manually deleting the folder and reinstalling.

Comment: I re-downloaded the latest SOE zip file. I thought I had the latest version but I guess not! Anyway it appears to be working. Thank you for your help!